# How to use ApprovalTests for approving logs

Tags: java, approval-tests

I want to use [Approval Tests](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Java) to verify log output. What is the preferred way to deal with dynamic content of the log text, e.g. time stamps? The included `FileApprover` always compares the files for exact equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple solutions to this. Here they are in order of preference:

1. Don't log dynamic content during the test.
2. Fake dynamic content during the test so the output is consistent.
3. Scrub the log file before comparing. This usually looks like:

   ```
   ScrubFile("log.txt", "log_scrubbed.txt", new DateScrubber(), new GuidScrubber())
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The concept remains the same as described by [llewellyn falco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1303587/llewellyn-falco). However, the API has changed in Approvals.Java.

```
val dynamicContentScrubber = RegExScrubber(pattern, replacement)
val scrubberOptions = Options(dynamicContentScrubber)

Approvals.verify(content, scrubberOptions)
```

Approvals.Java has a few built-in scrubbers like `DateScrubber`, `GuidScrubber`, and `RegexScrubber`. You can write your own by implementing the `org.approvaltests.core.Scrubber` interface.